# Getting error "type of expression must be an array type but it is resolved to Llist<WebElement>"

Tags: java, arrays, list, selenium-webdriver

Using Selenium Web driver in Java - trying to get all the values from a dropdown menu and storing to a list then checking if the given value is present in the list. If it is present then return true else false. I am new to selenium and learning things slowly kindly help me to resolve this issue. Thanks

```
 public void verifyResults() {
Boolean found=false;
    WebElement ele=driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/form/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/ul")); 
 Select sel = new Select(ele);
List<WebElement> el = sel.getOptions();
for(int i=0;i<el.size();i++){
     if(el[i].Equals("Agra")) {
          found=true;
break;
}
}
if(found){
     System.out.println(ele.getText());
}


   }
```

Answer (score 0):

`List`s in java don't have the `[]` operator, only arrays. Instead, you can use the `get` method.

Additionally, there are a few other problems in the snippet you shared. First, note that it's `equals`, not `Equals`. Second, the elements in `el` are `WebElement`s, not strings, so an element will never be equal to "Agra". I assume you meant to compare it with the text of the element:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < el.size(); i++){
     if (el.get(i).getText().equals("Agra")) {
          found = true;
          break;
     }
}
```

As a side note, it's worth noting that using streams could shorten the code considerably:

```java
boolean found = el.stream().anyMatch(e -> e.getText().equals("Agra"));
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But i am facing another issue as "List<WebElement> seems to be unrelated to String". So what can be used instead of List<WebElement> for storing list of values from the dropdown menu?